# How do I remove artifacts from my ContourPlot3D Valentine?

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, graphics3d

My version (below) of the "Valentine Formula" that [appeared](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/14/science/math-algorithm-valentine.html) in today's New York Times, has some ugly artifacts that don't appear in the NYT ([Java](https://love.imaginary.org)) version:

[image]

How do I remove these artifacts?

---

```
Manipulate[
    ContourPlot3D[(x^2+((1+b)*y)^2+z^2-1)^3-x^2*z^3-a*y^2*z^3 ==0,
        {x,-scale,scale},{y,-scale,scale},{z,-scale,scale},
        Mesh->None,Axes->None,Boxed->False,
        ContourStyle->Directive[Red,Opacity[0.8],Specularity[White,30]],
        PerformanceGoal->"Quality"
    ],
    {{a,.1},.0001,1},
    {{b,1},.00001,5},
    {{scale,1.25},1,5},
    SynchronousUpdating->False]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RegionPlot3D` can sometimes give cleaner results out of the box. I also upped the `PlotPoints` manually.

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[(x^2 + ((1 + b)*y)^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 - x^2*z^3 - 
    a*y^2*z^3 <= 0, {x, -scale, scale}, {y, -scale, 
   scale}, {z, -scale, scale}, Mesh -> None, Axes -> None, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[Automatic, 40]], {{a, .1}, .0001, 
  1}, {{b, 1}, .00001, 5}, {{scale, 1.25}, 1, 5}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: That's much nicer!

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `ContourPlot3D` option `PlotPoints -> n` where `n` is some number greater than or equal to 100 improved things considerably for me. There is still a very faint ring around the lower portion of the heart when I do this, but it's a considerable improvement.

The [`PlotPoints` argument](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) tells Mathematica how many points to use when initially sampling the plot. Many functions (including 2D functions like `DensityPlot`) accept this argument. For whatever reason, the default is often quite low for functions/plots with rapid changes or singularities.

Demo:

First, without any additional argument:
[image]

Then with `PlotPoints -> 200`.
[image: with argument]

Comment: That doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: @orome I bet you place the option in the `Directive` again.

Comment: @xzczd: Yep! (God I hate Mathematica's inadequate syntax checking!)

Comment: @orome I'm also surprised that _Mathematica_ doesn't give any warning in this case :D

Comment: It shows improvement now, but still shows (as you point out) artifacts that ruin it.